# Rotating cube through constant degree intervals is speeding up

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coding a rotating cube using rotation matrices and generating plots of the cube at equally spaced intervals along its rotation. However, I notice that the cube likes to speed up sometimes during the gif. Here is the code to generate the cube:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import sin, cos, radians as rad
import imageio
import os

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    
    def rotated(self, yaw, pitch, roll):
        x, y, z = self.x, self.y, self.z
        a, b, c = yaw, pitch, roll
        sa, sb, sc = sin(a), sin(b), sin(c)
        ca, cb, cc = cos(a), cos(b), cos(c)
        newx = (x*ca*cb + y*(ca*sb*sc-sa*cc) + z*(ca*sb*cc+sa*sc))
        newy = (x*sa*cb + y*(sa*sb*sc+ca*cc) + z*(sa*sb*cc-ca*sc))
        newz = (x*-sb   + y*cb*sc            + z*cb*cc) 
        return Point(newx, newy, newz)
    
def make_gif(fps):

    # creates images array and depth counter
    images, i = [], 1

    # adds images to the images array
    while True:
        try:
            images.append(imageio.imread(f"imgs/{i}.png"))
            i += 1
        except:
            break

    # saves the gif
    imageio.mimsave("plot.gif", images, fps=fps)

    # deletes all the images
    for i in range(1, len(images)+1):
        os.remove(f"imgs/{i}.png")

def rotating_gif(frames, fps, pitch, roll, yaw):

    ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
    points = [Point(x, y, z) for x in range(-5, 6) for y in range(-5, 6) for z in range(-5, 6)]

    i = 1

    for p, r, y in zip(np.linspace(0, pitch, frames), 
                       np.linspace(0, roll, frames), 
                       np.linspace(0, yaw, frames)):

        rotated = [point.rotated(p, r, y) for point in points]    

        x_vals = [point.x for point in rotated]
        y_vals = [point.y for point in rotated]
        z_vals = [point.z for point in rotated]

        ax.scatter3D(x_vals, y_vals, z_vals)
        ax.set_xlim(-7, 7)
        ax.set_ylim(-7, 7)
        ax.set_zlim(-7, 7)
        plt.grid(False)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.savefig(f"imgs/{i}.png")
        plt.cla()

        i += 1

    make_gif(fps)

def main():

    rotating_gif(240, 60, rad(-720), rad(720), rad(720)) 


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

For anyone that wants to reproduce it, here are my packages and versions:

```
matplotlib==3.7.1
numpy==1.24.3
imageio==2.9.0
```

Before running, you need to make a directory called `imgs`.

Comment: The pynterface imports are redundant.  Also, I get `No such file or directory: 'imgs/1.png'`

Comment: @Bill sorry, you need to make a directory called imgs

Comment: It's just an optical illusion.  Remember, when a sine wave gets its peaks (90 and 270), it changes relatively little from sample to sample, and your code is using the same wave for all three components.  If you offset the phases, you wouldn't see it.